# How to limit columns returned by Django query?

Tags: django, orm

That seems simple enough, but all Django Queries seems to be 'SELECT *'

How do I build a query returning only a subset of fields ?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

In Django 1.1 onwards, you can use `defer('col1', 'col2')` to exclude columns from the query, or `only('col1', 'col2')` to only get a specific set of columns. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#defer).

`values` does something slightly different - it only gets the columns you specify, but it returns a list of dictionaries rather than a set of model instances.

Comment: @Daniel, do you know why the documentation states to avoid these methods? It says they should be the last resort, and other methods should be exhausted first.

Comment: It gave me unpredictable result....
say I have model Employee and i do `qs=Employee.objects.all()` and `qs[0].pk` the result is instance however 
i do `qs2 = Employee.objects.all().filter(pk=1).only(id)` then `qs2[0].id` it took forever...

Comment: There is also values_list() which returns tuples instead of a dictionary (like with values() ).  Only() and Defer() return actual model objects but with missing data that will be loaded on-demand (which is quite costly, so make sure you know what you are doing).  So each has a different use case.

Comment: The answer about defer() and ony() methods may mislead. As Apollo Data pointed out, that will exclude the data from these fields, NOT the fields themselves.

Comment: I am noticing drastic performance issues when using `only()` on a PostGRES 9.5 table with about 7M rows. `Table.objects.all()[:10]` returns in under a second whereas `Table.objects.only('column_a','column_b').all()[:10]` never seems to finish. This is very apparently not equal to `select column_a, column_b from Table limit 10;`.

Comment: This would be a great answer if it actually included a code example or even a description of how `defer` and `only` should be used. Getting an answer from a single stack overflow page is superior to having to visit an additional documentation page. Ian does this well in the answer below.

Comment: @YungGun- Can't agree more. In the real world this is called **pecking order**. Had the answer been from a lesser mortal, there would be lots of bad blood, lots of skirmishes.

Answer (score 44):

Append a `.values("column1", "column2", ...)` to your query

Comment: A Note: If you use `.get()` instead of `.filter()` to get a specific object, and want to retrieve specific columns, you need to make sure `.values('field1',...)` is specified BEFORE the `.get()` method. If it is after, it generates an error because it gets the objects and then tried to run the `.values()` method on `model instance` instead of the `objects` property.

Comment: This answer is far better than the accepted answer (Because it actually answers the question. Saying "look at the docs" or "use this or that" without a code example is not a real answer). I'm already using QuerySet.values(), too, so that makes it even easier. Thanks!

Comment: The only downside is `.values()` automatically end up deserialize into `dict` instead of the original object class.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer advises `defer` and `only`, however [the docs discourage this in most cases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#defer).

> only use defer() when you cannot, at queryset load time, determine if you will need the extra fields or not. If you are frequently loading and using a particular subset of your data, the best choice you can make is to normalize your models and put the non-loaded data into a separate model (and database table). If the columns must stay in the one table for some reason, create a model with Meta.managed = False (see the managed attribute documentation) containing just the fields you normally need to load and use that where you might otherwise call defer(). This makes your code more explicit to the reader, is slightly faster and consumes a little less memory in the Python process.