# Django - how do I select a particular column from a model?

Tags: django

I had a sniff around SO and couldn't find this, but I am sure it is here somewhere. Apologies for this potential double post!

If I have this code:

```
return Story.objects.filter(user=request.user.id).order_by('-create_date')
```

and say Story has, um, a "description" field, and I *just* want that description field, no need for the db to send anything else back with my result, how do I limit the query to *just* that?

That is, how do I generate this SQL:

```
select description from story where user_id = x order by create_date desc
```

(where x is the request.user.id value, of course)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit columns returned by Django query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448978/how-to-limit-columns-returned-by-django-query)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use `values()` or `values_list()`.

If you use `values()`, You'll end up with a list of dictionaries (technically a `ValuesQuerySet`)

```
instance = MyModel.objects.values('description')[0]
description = instance['description']
```

If you use `values_list()`, you'll end up with a list of tuples

```
instance = MyModel.objects.values_list('description')[0]
description = instance[0]
```

Or if you're just getting one value like in this case, you can use the `flat=True` kwarg with `values_list` to get a simple list of values

```
description = MyModel.objects.values_list('description', flat=True)[0]
```

See the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values)

Comment: Correct: `return Story.objects.filter(user=request.user.id).order_by('-create_date').values('description')`

Comment: @bharal lots of times I find a list of values is more usedful than a list of tuples.  You can pass `flat=True` to `values_list` to get a list of values

Comment: what if I want to get a jsonb field data as it is?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`only` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only). Please read the documentation

Comment: This actually sends back `pk` as well

Comment: um, from the documentation i just read: The defer() method (and its cousin, only(), below) are only for advanced use-cases. They provide an optimization for when you have analyzed your queries closely and understand exactly what information you need and have measured that the difference between returning the fields you need and the full set of fields for the model will be significant.

Answer (score 0):

As the docs says if the your query set is going to yield only one object, it's recommended that you should use get() instead of filter. From the name that you've given, I would assume that user_id is distinct for every user.
EDIT1 : I just took a notice of orderby clause. So I would suggest to use this code if the user_id is distinct or with pk.

```
    description = story.objects.filter('description').get(user_id=x)
```

Comment: The question is about how to select a particular column values from a given table using Django ORM.