# Concatenate Properties of Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Can I join Django ORM Model properties/attributes into a string without introducing loops?

I have a django model:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, db_collation='Latin1_General_CI_AS')
```

I want to select the names into a string from a result of filtering:

```py
foos = Foo.objects.filter(id=[1,2,3])
```

Something equivalent of this piece of C#:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
        foos.Add(new Foo { Name = "A1" });
        foos.Add(new Foo { Name = "A2" });
        
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", foos.Select(x => x.Name)));
    }
}
```

Which outputs `A1,A2`.

Comment: `",".join(foos.values_list("name", flat=True))`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate (join) items in a list to a single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-join-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string) along with [Django - how do I select a particular column from a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704926/django-how-do-i-select-a-particular-column-from-a-model)