# select particular field in python

Tags: python, mysql, performance, select

Hi i need to fetch all rows for particular field from database right now i am using

```
 mygame.objects.all()
```

which fetches all fields say

> x ,y , z and so on

and so on but i need to **select** only

> x and y
>   so there will be a less **load** on **database** and the performance can be **improved** 
>    please suggest how can i do this

Comment: Use [queryset.only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check the [FAQ - How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. Your question is missing some information to get a good answer, such as what is `mygame`? What is `objects`? What does the `all()` method do? If this is django related, please add the django tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:-

```
mygame.objects.all().only('x','y')
```

This might be helpful:-

[How to limit columns returned by Django query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448978/how-to-limit-columns-returned-by-django-query)